# How fast is the distance between two points changing.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am having a difficulty with the following question from my calculus unit.

Bus station A is located 100km west of bus station B. At 12pm a bus leaves station A driving south at 70km/h and a bus leaves station B at 50km/h going north. How fast is the distance between the buses changing at 2pm?

Thanks.

Comment: What direction does bus from station $B$ go? Can you write a formula for the distance between the buses at time $t$?

Comment: Missed that, bus B goes north. d = sqrt(10000 + (50t + 70t)^2)

Comment: Looks good. Now what do you need to do to find how quickly distance is changing with respect to time?

Comment: It could actually simplify to d = sqrt(10000 + 14400t^2) and I need Derivative, right?

Comment: Yep, that's right, and yes, the next step is to take the derivative.

Comment: 14400t/sqrt(10000+14400t^2)

Comment: Yep, that's the derivative. Now what value of $t$ should you plug in to find how fast the distance is changing at $2$pm (and what should the units of this value be)?

Comment: Okay, so slope is 1440/13 or the distance between the two buses is increasing by about 110.77 km/h

Comment: Exactly! Good job.